# I want Nav Bar to be fixed and transparent while over the wrapper div, upon scrolling beyond this div it should remain how it is now

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

I have created a page on Pen
https://codepen.io/nenadmail/pen/KmRbGO

I want the Nav Bar to be fixed position and transparent bkg while over the .wrap div, upon scolling past this div the nav bar should behave exactly the way it is now, which is to automatically hide and have a gray background (#1f1f1f). One example web site where I've seen this function work with their navigation is: http://www.blitzagency.com

```
.maintop {
height: 58px;
background: #1f1f1f; /* I want no background color over wrapper div*/
z-index: 100;
}
```

Thanks!

Here's the HTML below:

```
    <div class="wrapper" id="home">
    <header class="header" role="banner">
    <div class="maintop">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
     <div class="maintopL">
        <a href="#home">
            <h1 id="mainlogo">N2Mix</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
</div>

<div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only 
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, rem 
aining essentially unchanged. <a href ="#">I want this link to work 
even when it is near the nav bar</a>It was popularised in the 1960s 
with the release of Letraset sheets containing. </p>
<p> Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
```

Here is the current javascript code. But the chane I need is for the .header class to be fixed and transparent while scrolling over the wrapper with the video background:

```
;( function ( document, window, index )
{
    'use strict';

    var elSelector  = '.header',
        element     = document.querySelector( elSelector );

    if( !element ) return true;

    var elHeight        = 0,
        elTop           = 0,
        dHeight         = 0,
        wHeight         = 0,
        wScrollCurrent  = 0,
        wScrollBefore   = 0,
        wScrollDiff     = 0;

    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function()
    {
        elHeight        = element.offsetHeight;
        dHeight         = document.body.offsetHeight;
        wHeight         = window.innerHeight;
        wScrollCurrent  = window.pageYOffset;
        wScrollDiff     = wScrollBefore - wScrollCurrent;
        elTop           = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( element ).getPropertyValue( 'top' ) ) + wScrollDiff;

        if( wScrollCurrent <= 0 ) // scrolled to the very top; element sticks to the top
            element.style.top = '0px';

        else if( wScrollDiff > 0 ) // scrolled up; element slides in
            element.style.top = ( elTop > 0 ? 0 : elTop ) + 'px';

        else if( wScrollDiff < 0 ) // scrolled down
        /*{
          if( wScrollCurrent + wHeight >= dHeight - elHeight )  // scrolled to the very bottom; element slides in
            element.style.top = ( ( elTop = wScrollCurrent + wHeight - dHeight ) < 0 ? elTop : 0 ) + 'px';

            *////else // scrolled down; element slides out
                element.style.top = ( Math.abs( elTop ) > elHeight ? -elHeight : elTop ) + 'px';
        ////}

        wScrollBefore = wScrollCurrent;
    });

}( document, window, 0 ));
```

Comment: Why is JAVA in the title?

Comment: Perhaps the solution could be java

Comment: Wait... no, I thought that was a joke. It can't be JAVA - unless you scrap everything you've done and write it all in JAVA. - it might be JavaScript though.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the title to say Javascript

Comment: A website example that does exactly what I'm trying to do with my navigation is: www.blitzagency.com  I'm not advanced enough to figure out how they did it. :( please help!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask